# Installed Python Modules - Python can't find them

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

This is a beginner `python` installation question.  This the first time I have tried to install and call a package.  I've got `pip` installed, and I tried to install two modules - `numpy` and `pandas`.

In terminal, I ran the following commands:

```
sudo pip install numpy

sudo pip install pandas
```

Both commands returned with a success message.  Here is the `pandas` success message (it's the second package I installed and was still in my terminal history):

```
Successfully installed pandas
Cleaning up...
```

`pip` returned a similar message after `numpy` was installed.

Now, when I launch `python` and try to call it with:

```
import pandas
```

I get this error message:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> ImportError: No module named pandas
> ```

Same when I try `numpy`.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: No, not necessarily. But if you were, you would need to make sure the virtualenv was activated before your imports would work. But ignore my comment, since it does not seem to be relevant.

Comment: Just as a note, any particular reason you can't just use your normal package manager to install these?

Comment: @Lattyware - With the admission of being a beginner - Which package manager should I be using?  Reading online, it seems `pip` was preferred over `easy_install`.

Comment: Largely depends on what distro you are using. For me under arch, it's a case of `sudo pacman -s python-numpy` and grabbing pandas of the AUR.

Comment: any chance you have two versions of python installed and are installing to one then checking in the other (been there myself ;)

Comment: @Lattyware: Using pip will get newer versions than using the system packae manager (apt, pacman, yum, etc).

Comment: @Nicolas78 I'm on OS X 10.7, which comes installed with a python version.  Then, via `homebrew`, I installed 2.7.2 - so what you're suggesting might be the cause.  How can I tell my machine to work with 2.7.2 rather than the default?  Thanks...

Comment: @jgomo3 Sometimes, but it's not often that will matter too much, either way, just thought I'd mention it in case it made the OP's life easier.

Comment: @mikebmassey use distribute/pip http://python-distribute.org/pip_distribute.png

Comment: ok so when you run python, does it start the 2.7 or the old one? if it's the new, try to find the path to pip (whereis pip I guess? not on OS X). if it's at another path than your 2.7, try finding a pip installation under 2.7, or reinstall it using python2.7 as a ocmmand line

Comment: @mikebmassey i installed them and imported as you say without problems. I noticed that the installation implies some C code compilation, so i needed the Python header files. Just in case, find some python-dev package and install it with you system package manager.

Of course, the installation should failed if you didn't installed the necessary files for compilation... but just in case.

Comment: OK - I'm on to something.  When I type `which python`, I get: `/usr/bin/python`.  Shouldn't that be `/usr/local/bin/python` ?  Or does that even matter?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

argh.  you've got two pythons in your path that are the same version?  don't do that.

pip, easy-install, etc are associated with a particular python install and will use that python by default.  so if you have a system-provided python and a system-provided easy_install (or installed easy_install yourself using the system python) then easy_install will, by default, install packages for the system python.

the best way to avoid this mess, imho, is to use use system python for that version (2.7 probably) and, for other versions, use `make alt-install` when installing, which will give you executables like `python3.1` and the like.  if you really need to replace the version provided by the system, uninstall it.

once you've done that. each python will have a distinct name (ending in the version) and `python` will remain the system one.

next, when you install easy_install, you'll notice that there are version-specific versions (`easy_install-2.7` for example).  use those.  if one is missing, then install distutils with the appropriate python (eg use `python3.1` and you'll get an `easy_install-3.1`).  unfortunately, each time you do this (iirc) you overwrite the un-versioned `easy_install`, so *never* use that - always use the versioned one.

alternatively, you could not install easy_install or pip for anything other than the system version, then *always use virtualenv*.  virtualenv will let you specify a python version (so you can use the system virtualenv for all pythons installed) and then installs easy_install/pip for the python you use.  so once you're inside the virtual environment, everything just works.

and i just realised i haven't much experience with pip, so i can't actually help with that (except to note that virtualenv does provide it) (about which is preferable: it used to be that pip was better maintained; i think these days the latest distutils/easy_install is as good as pip, but pip has a few more features that i have never used).

disclaimer: the above is from experience gained developing lepl, which runs on 2.6 to 3.2, so i need to test it on all those.  as far as i know, what i describe above works for me, but i have no deep knowledge of python/easy_install/pip so i may have some mistakes in rationalising/describing things (in other words, i'm writing all this in case it helps, but i'm a bit worried i have an error - please, someone correct me if so).

Answer (score 0):

With this, I solve the problem (may help you):

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pandas
$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

Comment: Have you even determined what OS the OP is on?