# Getting 'module' object has no attribute 'Series' when pandas installed

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to be able to use Pandas on my computer to work with data. I've been able to do this fine in iPython notebooks. But on my computer, when I try to use anything from Pandas, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/pandas.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Users/Desktop/pandas.py", line 7, in <module>
    s = pd.Series([1,3,5,np.nan,6,8])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Series'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

I've checked to make sure that pandas is installed on my computer. When I run `pip install pandas` I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pandas in /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz>=2011k in /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.6.1 in /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas)
Cleaning up...
```

which seems to indicate that pandas is already installed.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run a script in your desktop directory and there is another script called pandas.py in the same place. If that's the case then your import statement is importing /Users/Desktop/pandas.py instead of the pandas lib.

Comment: That is it. I deleted the file. When I try to run now, it just says 'no module named pandas.' Any idea what the error would be that's causing that? I checked that I had pandas installed.

Comment: Is there a `pandas.pyc` file on your desktop also?

Comment: I deleted that, but moved it back on to the desktop. Not sure what that's for...reading about it now...

Comment: Also, you can see which file is being used via `pd.__file__`, as mentioned by others, calling file the same name as another module is recipe for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to see what version of python you are using?  It seems that you installed pandas in python27.  Is that traceback from a script written in python27 also?  If not, then that will cause issues.

The answer to this question has a good explanation:  [Installed Python Modules - Python can't find them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376647/installed-python-modules-python-cant-find-them)